# What is BookmarkID in VBA for Word

Tags: vba

I took the following two lines of code from the site http://blogs.infoextract.in/bookmark-object-word-vba/

```
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InfoExtractBookmark").Range.BookmarkID

 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("InfoExtractBookmark").Select
```

When I run the first line of code in VBA Editor in Word, it is reporting an error. The second line does not report any error when I ran it alone. Even though bookmarking is there in the document, it does not get selected.

Could anyone explain please?

Comment: *When I run the first line of code in VBA Editor in Word, it is reporting an error.* `BookmarkID` is a property which must be assigned to something (variable of proper type, for example). You cannot call it as a method, or you must specify`Call` keyword (in that case the code is executed, but the returned value will be lost).

Comment: @Akina Based on your comment, I assigned it to a integer variable and got the total number of bookmarks which in the present case was just 1 only.

Comment: *I assigned it to a integer variable and got the total number of bookmarks which in the present case was just 1 only.* No, you got specified bookmark identifier, not bookmarks count. Their equality is an accident.

Comment: Oh my God. Understood your point. @Akina